# Bias code and text while saving

Tags: visual-studio-code

Tell  me how to fix the problem?
Every time I save a document, the lines of code are shifted to 1 one whole line. How can I disable this? Thank you

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    Username <input type="text"><br> Pasword <input type="password"><br>
    <input type="button">Button<br>


</form>
```

Comment: What is your editor ?

Comment: Visual studio code

Comment: Have you looked at the help documentation for the relevant program, looked at the FAQ, contacted their support team?

Comment: He looked at the inquiry, found nothing.
decided to ask you, the service responded for a long time.

Comment: @JohnShevchenko Could you add your VSCode user settings in your question ?

Comment: There are many settings. What kind of show?

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode

1. Open the user settings `File > Preferences > Settings`
2. In the search bar enter `save`
3. Set `editor.formatOnSave` to `false`
4. Look for any other settings that may do something to your code on save and disable them also

Comment: At me all so is adjusted. Please look at the video to understand exactly my problem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTIHXtFEMBc&feature=youtu.be